# Chrome Web Store Review Without Google Plus

Tags: chrome-web-store

I submitted an extension to Chrome Web Store but as a developer, if I reply to a support review my Google Plus account is published.

Is it possible to hide Google Plus account? If not, do you recommend to create another account without breaking Chrome TOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another account for that. Google's [Publishing tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish) says:

> decide which Google Account you want to be your **developer account**.
>   This account will own your app (or multiple apps, if you choose) and
>   will receive any payments you get from Chrome Web Store Payments.
>   Instead of your personal account, you might want to choose a dedicated
>   account.